# Salesforce How to send an automated email prior to a scheduled activity

Tags: email, salesforce, apex

I have scheduled activities for each customer. I would like to send them a reminder email a day before the event occurs. SF says this cannot be done directly as only 5 non SF users can receive emails.

They say it can be done via custom code in Apex. Before I go down that route I was wondering if they are correct. I know we have other Workflow rules where we send emails to thousands of non SF users. For example, all new leads receive an email.

Am I missing something here? SF was adamant that it's not possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can only add up to 5 additional email addresses when creating workflow email alerts, that is documented here

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_alerts.htm

There's nothing to prevent you from adding an email address that is an actual distribution list, so in reality you can send emails to a lot of people. Now I'm not sure I understand the use case nor sfdc's answer. You can certainly set this up with workflows, even if you have 10K customers, the limit they are referring to is about a single workflow execution, for a given record, can only email 5 additional email addresses, but said workflow can still fire for thousands of records.

I'd confirm the use case before using Apex.